# Extension of the uniqueness theorem in electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics

I came across the uniqueness theorem in Griffiths while studying electrostatics. In Griffiths, it is emphasized that the charge density while solving poisson's equation must be zero. This is given as a justification for the method of images technique to simplify systems. As long as the boundary conditions are defined in a given volume of zero charge density, we can find only one potential function describing that volume.

I wondered why you couldn't extend it to non zero charge density, and I wrote a proof below(very similar to the one mentioned in Griffiths).

Poisson's equation says that:$$\nabla^2V=-\rho/\epsilon_0$$
Now for a given volume, let us assume that the boundary conditions of the potential function are defined.

Assume that there exist two such functions, $V_1$ and $V_2$ that represent the potential function inside this volume with the same boundary conditions.

This implies that:$$\nabla^2V_1=-\rho/\epsilon_0$$ $$\nabla^2V_2=-\rho/\epsilon_0$$
Now the take consider: $V_3=V_2-V_1$ $$\Rightarrow\nabla^2(V_3)=\nabla^2V_2 - \nabla^2V_1=-\rho/\epsilon_0+\rho/\epsilon_0=0$$

Now this gives us poisson's equation and we know the extrema of the potential lie around the boundary. Since the boundary are the same for $V_1$ and $V_2$ $\Rightarrow V_3=V_2-V_1=0$ around the boundary. Hence the extrema of $V_3$ are $0$ which implies that $V_3=0$ everywhere. Hence  $$V_1=V_2$$ throughout the volume.

Now this means that in a given volume, for a given charge density function, with same boundary conditions, there exists only one potential function describing the potential in that volume.

I was wondering if this statement would be true at all.

Comment: This looks like the standard argument for uniqueness. So, where is the extension?

Comment: Yes, this is the usual derivation of uniqueness of electric potential (for given boundary values of potential and charge distribution).

Comment: $\nabla^2V=0$ is called Laplace's equation. It is a particular case of Poisson's equation ( $\rho \ne 0$).

Comment: Well in this link here: http://teacher.pas.rochester.edu/PHY217/LectureNotes/Chapter3/LectureNotesChapter3.html

Comment: This was how it was mentioned in griffiths@oliver